# Tool for conversion of PDD-format images?

Tags: file-conversion, photos

I've got a collection of a few thousand images (scans of very old family photographs) created using the native format of Adobe PhotoDeluxe 3, and I'm trying to convert them into something more usable on modern machines. What programs exist for doing this? The format (with extension PDD) seems to be not commonly supported, and in my Googling for possible solutions it seems that most people who have images like this are really working with images produced by some version of Photoshop, which did *not* produce these.

In my searching I have found mention of:

- Using a trial version of Photoshop
- Using IrfanView
- Using GIMP
- Using XnView

Of these, IrfanView doesn't actually list PDD among the supported formats, so I suspect it is a bust. GIMP supports plugins, but I can't find whether there are any plugins for the format I've got to deal with. I can believe Photoshop would support this format (after all, it's by the same company that produced the originating software) and XnView actually lists the format (if a little unclearly). Are there others I should know about?

*Other constraints:*
I'd prefer there to be versions of the program for both Windows (ideally XP) and OSX, due to the fact that I want to also recommend the program to family members who have archival copies of the files, but it's not critical. I would also, because of the sheer number, prefer something that will do batch conversions; I still have the original software in working condition but conversion is slow with it and totally manual and I'd rather not commit a month of spare time to working on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a while, I've returned to looking at this and I found a shareware package called [Total Image Converter](http://www.coolutils.com/totalimageconverter) which does exactly what I want on Windows 7. In particular, it copes with the PDD format variation that my old scanned images are actually stored in (as opposed to other members of the cluster of Adobe formats under the same name!) and it can do bulk conversions without a separate automation tool. As a down-side, it does not appear to be available for other platforms, but I can at least now convert to something much more conventional like TIFF.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ImageConverter Plus](http://www.imageconverterplus.com/download/)

Answer (score 0):

Including an answer to this old post to mention that Adobe's Photoshop CS2 *(permanent non-trial version)* is freely available and has been so for years.

Before they stopped offering it themselves, they did provide an activation key.
Just fill out the required fields as well. Despite the fact that you can not register it, it is not a trial version that will expire after 30 days.

[Techspot.com](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/3689-adobe-photoshop-cs2.html) still provides it for download along with activation keys for Windows and Macs.

After the download use the following info to finalize installation.

> **Activation Key:** 1045-1412-5685.1654.6343-1431
>
> **DISABLE REGISTRATION POPUP**
>
> - Go to Photoshop installation directory. One of following ways:
>
>   - **Right-click** on the Photoshop CS2 shortcut, choose **Open file location**
>     Windows Explorer will open correspondingly the folder on system (x86/64).
>
>     - c:\Program Files\Adobe\Photoshop CS2 on 32bit system.
>     - c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Photoshop CS2 on 64bit system.
>   - In Windows Explorer, navigate to one of two above folders, correspondingly to your current system.
> - **Delete the file:**  `regsresen_us.dll`

*source: [youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv8esKK2nGM) (for Windows installation)*

I have been using CS2 for years as a home hobbyist and was still able to get additional Plug-ins and Tools from Adobe (*this may still require making an account*)